Using matplotlib to draw a function, but it only show half
I want to replicate this video using Matplotlib, but what I've got until now it's just the right half of the image, as you can see below:

Here it is my code, it's not totally wrong but of course I'm missing something, could you please help in finding my mistake?
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from math import e, pi, sin

def f(x, a):
   x = np.clip(x, -np.sqrt(np.pi), np.sqrt(np.pi))
   return x**(2/3) + e/3 * np.maximum (0, (pi - x**2)**0.5) * np.sin(a * pi * x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 400)
line, = ax.plot(x, f(x, 0), lw=2, color='red')  
ax.set_xlim([-2, 2])
ax.set_ylim([-1.5, 2.5])
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('f(x)')
ax.set_title('f(x) = x^(2/3) + e/3*(π-x^2)^1/2*sin(a*π*x)')

def update(a):

  line.set_ydata(f(x, a))  
  ax.set_title(f'f(x) =  x^(2/3) + e/3*(π-x^2)^1/2*sin({a:.1f}πx)')
  return line,


frames = np.arange(0, 20, 0.05)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=frames, interval=10, blit=True)


plt.show()`


That is because your function f(x, a) contains x**(2/3), which returns complex number when x < 0. Simply replace x with np.abs(x), and remove blit=True to make the matplotlib work. Your code should look like this.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from math import e, pi, sin

def f(x, a):
   x = np.clip(x, -np.sqrt(np.pi), np.sqrt(np.pi))
   return np.abs(x)**(2/3) + e/3 * np.maximum (0, (pi - x**2)**0.5) * np.sin(a * pi * x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 400)
line, = ax.plot(x, f(x, 0), lw=2, color='red')  
ax.set_xlim([-2, 2])
ax.set_ylim([-1.5, 2.5])
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('f(x)')
ax.set_title('f(x) = x^(2/3) + e/3*(π-x^2)^1/2*sin(a*π*x)')

def update(a):

  line.set_ydata(f(x, a))  
  ax.set_title(f'f(x) =  x^(2/3) + e/3*(π-x^2)^1/2*sin({a:.1f}πx)')
  return line,


frames = np.arange(0, 20, 0.05)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=frames, interval=10, blit=True)


plt.show()

Cheers~

(x**2)**(1/3)
